# Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer - how to query column containing JSON string

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I am trying to perform a filtering using the query as shown in the image below, expecting it to filter specific matching rows.  But, it doesn't filter the matching rows.

Any thoughts on how to limit it, short of exporting it to a file?  I think it has something to do with the string representing a JSON object.

THe purpose of filtering the table is to quickly filter and delete the matching rows from the table in the UI.

Greatly appreciate any insights/inputs into this.

Thank you
Regards
Athadu

[[image: Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer query[1]]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have encountered an issue with Storage Explorer. The query should work. When I switched to the text view (from designer view), I noticed that Storage Explorer is complaining about the query:

[image]

I would recommend opening up an issue here: https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues.

BTW, there's nothing wrong with the query. When I execute the same query in Cerebrata Cerulean (full disclosure: I am building the tool), I am able to fetch the data properly.

[image]

Comment: @Mantri-Thank you

I have tried following - with no luck:

// no encoded or escaped values
DataKey eq '{ "id": "002427", "type": "E" }' - bad req

// colon and comma - encoded value
DataKey eq '{ "id"%3A "002427"%2C "type"%3A "E" }' - bad req

// curly-brace, colon and comma - encoded value
DataKey eq '%7B "id"%3A "002427"%2C "type"%3A "E" %7D' - bad req

// comma replace with encoded value - double-quotes escaped 
DataKey eq '{ ""id""%3A ""002427""%2C ""type""%3A ""E"" }' - no data

// comma replace with encoded valued
DataKey eq '{ "id": "002427"%2C "type": "E" }' - bad req

Comment: You really don't need to do any encoding.